# Keep AppleScript running and checking for URLs

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I'm trying to create an AppleScript in macOS application that is running while the open browser is running and redirecting certain URLs to a specific URL. This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
if \(start) is false then
 error number -128
end if
 repeat until application "Safari" is not running
   if application "Safari" is running then
    tell application "Safari"
      set myList to \(fixedSites) as list
      repeat with theItem in myList
      set (URL of every tab of every window where URL contains theItem) to "https://stackoverflow.com"
   end repeat
  end tell
 end if
end repeat
```

I'm using a boolean in the script to make it stop after the user has decided. Still, the problem with my example is that it blocks my application (I can use any other in the system, but it seems that repeat loops are too resource-intensive as it cranks up the CPU usage. I've tried using idle/end idle too, but that doesn't seem to trigger this script.

Comment: Try adding a `delay 1` inside the loop. As is, it repeats the loop as soon as it can set the url. Of course, you can increase or decrease the delay as required.

Comment: Those tight repeat loops don’t give the system any time to process events.  The idle handler uses a timer, and is started after the run handler finishes, so the app needs to be saved as stay-open.

Comment: "idle and quit Handlers for Stay-Open Applications" (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html)